# change reactbootstrap navbar toggle icon.(Styled components)

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap, styled-components

Is there any way to change the **Navbar.Toggle** (React-bootstrap) button icon  to a custom one using styled components?

I need to display different icons according to whether navbar is open/closed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can change it using `background-image` property.

**DEFAULT**

```
.navbar-toggler-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='30' height='30' viewBox='0 0 30 30'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-width='2' d='M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22'/%3E%3C/svg%3E)
}
```

**Your logo**

```
.navbar-toggler-icon {
    background-image: url("yourpath_of_img")
}
```

**WITH STYLE COMPONENTS**

```
const Thing = styled.div`
  .navbar-toggler-icon {
      background-image: url("yourpath_of_img")
  }`
```

Comment: i am using styled components.

Comment: so, what, its same in both case

Comment: here where will i put the 'thing' component? if i'm not placing it anywhere it will show as a warning

Comment: you can wrap it as HOC of `Navbar.Toggle`

Comment: If you like my answer or you got any help from my answer, don't forget to consider up-vote and check this answer as the best answer for you by clicking on the right arrow, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the border as well to remove the border.

```
.navbar-toggler {
  border-color: black;
}
```